# I just don't understand this pointer case

Tags: c, pointers

This is my code:

```
int *p;
p=4;
printf("p is %p\n",p);
free(p);
//need p=NULL but I don't
int *q;
q=5:
printf("q is %i",*q);
```

Then the error comes.
I just need explanation for it.

Comment: Ignoring the typo (`Int` should be `int`--case matters), p is a pointer to an integer.  You then assign it the address 4.  But 4 is not the address of an int, and it wasn't allocated by you, so you can't free it.

Answer (score 3):

```
int *p;
```

is a pointer to an int.

```
p = 4;
```

makes it point to the address `0x4`

```
free(p);
```

try to deallocate the address 0x4

basically you are trying to free a ressource that can not be freed.

```
int *q;
q = 5;
```

points q to the address `0x5;

```
*q;
```

reads from the `0x5` address, which most likely will crash. (also this address is not aligned).

Pointers are not integers... the program you wrote shows a lack of understanding of what pointers are and why/how they should be used.

Comment: Now i get it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
Int *p; // You had better use int* p = NULL; we don't like wild pointers
//p = new int;
p=4; // I guess you want put the value of 4 to a variable, so *p = 4;
printf("p is %p\n",p);//    printf("p is %d\n",*p);
free(p);//just correct in theory, no one can tell what happens in reality.
/* 
if ( NULL != p )
{
    delete p;
    p = NULL;
}
*/
```

Comment: Note that `*p = 4;` wouldn't be much of an improvement if `p == NULL`; the code would probably crash writing through the null pointer.  You also haven't directly addressed the crash when accessing `q` — there are multiple issues with that part of the code fragment too.

Comment: What i did is just to comment, just tell the author. You are so nervous.